# Asking for refs: formalisms that admit {x}={{x}}

Tags: alternative-set-theories

I have some interest in alternative formulations of set theory which blatantly admit {x}={{x}}. What gave rise to such interest is the following. Take the set equation A={A}. The RHS dictate that {A} contains one element. So since A={A}, A is also of cardinality 1. We therefore get {x}={{x}} which has no solution. But if we admitted that {x}={{x}}, we could have a solution: A can be any set of a single element. Under such formalism, therefore, set equations become more "algebrically closed".

I'll be thankful if anyone can point me to such existing formalisms of set theory as I didn't find any.

Edit:
we will need to give up the regularity axiom
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_set_is_an_element_of_itself
but that's the edge of my knowledge

Comment: Are you looking for set theories where $\forall x.\{x\}=\{\{x\}\}$ holds, or just ones where there are particular $x$ that satisfy $\{x\}=\{\{x\}\}$?

Comment: as long as we can have a solution for A={A}, I wouldn't mind really. But consider the following argument: physically, {x}={{x}} indeed. The set that contains the sun is no more than the sun. So one could philosophically consider it for any x.

Comment: If $A=\{A\} \forall A$, then $\emptyset =\{\emptyset\}$, so $0=1$. So you could not use the Neumann definition of natural numbers.

Comment: @TroyMcClure, based on this comment it seems that you are interested in something like second-order logic rather than a set theory: this allows one to talk about objects and collections of objects, but nothing else/deeper. A set theory where the equation $\{a\} = \{\{a\}\}$ holds more generally based on the idea that it "ultimately" contains the same elements would be very weird; in particular, from $\{a\} = \{\{a\}\}$ you should be able to conclude $a = \{a\}$, which is false when $a$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are well-studied set theories where the equation $x=\{x\}$ has a solution (and therefore also $\{x\}=\{\{x\}\}$, of course). Such a solution is sometimes called a [Quine atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Quine_atoms).

Look for [non-well-founded set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory), and for the [anti-foundation axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom) in particular.

---

On the other hand, having $\forall x.\{x\}=\{\{x\}\}$ would require major changes to our conception of sets, and I'm not sure the result would be recognizable as *set theory* at all.

In particular, the notation $\{x\}$ is usually taken to mean "a set whose *only* element is $x$", so if $\{x\}=\{\{x\}\}$, then we have one set whose only element is simultaneously $x$ and $\{x\}$. This means that $x=\{x\}$, or again that the only element of $x$ is $x$ itself.

So in such a theory, if you want *any* set that contains two different things (or just something different from itself), you would need to give up the usual interpretation of $\{\cdots\}$ in terms of $\in$.

Trying to work out what you want to put instead, you might end up reinventing some form of [mereology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mereology).

Comment: And also $\{\varnothing\}=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ would require a new way of thinking about $\varnothing$ and about $=$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I suspect after redefining $\{\cdots\}$ such that $\forall x. \{x\}=\{\{x\}\}$ is possible, we would end up having $\{\varnothing\}$ mean the same thing as $\varnothing$ anyway. (Lots of confused freshmen rejoice?)